# Applying the Same Padding Value from Parent to Child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, padding

How would I apply a `padding-top` value, from a parent element, to a child `div` within it, using JQuery?

In the example below, the `div.video-wrapper` generates a `padding-top` value of `75%`. Because this value will be automatically generated on load, (and will change variably), I cannot apply this exact `padding-top` value manually; thus, I am looking towards a JQuery solution.

In short, I am looking to apply the `padding-top` value from the `div.video-wrapper` to the div with the class `thumbnail-inner-container`.

Here is an example of the generated HTML:

```
<div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 75%;">
    <div class="thumbnail-outer-container">
        <div class="thumbnail-inner-container">
            <a href="#" class="yt-hd-thumbnail yt-hd-thumbnail-darken">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxx/hqdefault.jpg">
            </a>
            <iframe id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0" class="yt-hd-thumbnail" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your page, Do you have multiple `thumbnail-inner-container` in one `video-wrapper` or  several `video-wrapper` with inside one `thumbnail-inner-container`?

Comment: The second case you mentioned; although, I was able to figure out a solution by utilizing `padding-top: inherit` on both `thumbnail-outer-container` and `thumbnail-inner-container`. As of now, I can't officially mark any solutions for this question yet.

Comment: Well, if you want I can try to help you, but if you have found another good way to resolve it maybe now it is not so important for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `.thumbnail-inner-container`'s `style.paddingTop` as `.video-wrapper`'s `style.paddingTop`.

```html
<div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 75%;">
    <div class="thumbnail-outer-container">
        <div class="thumbnail-inner-container">
            <a href="#" class="yt-hd-thumbnail yt-hd-thumbnail-darken">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxx/hqdefault.jpg">
            </a>
            <iframe id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0" class="yt-hd-thumbnail" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail-inner-container")[0].style.paddingTop = document.getElementsByClassName("video-wrapper")[0].style.paddingTop;
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like a plausible solution, but it somehow isn't working for me...

Comment: @nrweb Do you have more than one element with the class `thumbnail-inner-container`?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple elements with that class.

Answer (score 0):

So, as you mentioned in your comment, `padding-top: inherit` is a good solution without using jQuery.

However, a jQuery way to resolve your problem is to add a `video-wrapper` loop. For each `video-wrapper` we find in the page, we add its own class to 'thumbnail-inner-container` child.

The result is a solution very similar to **Hev1**'s one, with the add of a loop and jQuery.

You can check the result inspecting with a browser debug bar this code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".video-wrapper").each(function(){
    var myVideo=$(this);
    var myPaddingTop=myVideo.attr('style');
    $(".thumbnail-inner-container", myVideo).attr("style", myPaddingTop);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 75%;">
    <div class="thumbnail-outer-container">
        <div class="thumbnail-inner-container">
            <a href="#" class="yt-hd-thumbnail yt-hd-thumbnail-darken">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxx/hqdefault.jpg">
            </a>
            <iframe id="youtube_iframe1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0" class="yt-hd-thumbnail" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 70%;">
    <div class="thumbnail-outer-container">
        <div class="thumbnail-inner-container">
            <a href="#" class="yt-hd-thumbnail yt-hd-thumbnail-darken">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxx/hqdefault.jpg">
            </a>
            <iframe id="youtube_iframe2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0" class="yt-hd-thumbnail" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 24%;">
    <div class="thumbnail-outer-container">
        <div class="thumbnail-inner-container">
            <a href="#" class="yt-hd-thumbnail yt-hd-thumbnail-darken">
                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxxx/hqdefault.jpg">
            </a>
            <iframe id="youtube_iframe3" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" name="fitvid0" class="yt-hd-thumbnail" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```